# In Global.asax file, Scheduler is not working on Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

In Global.asax mentioned Job Scheduler.
Scheduler is working on specific period but when I upload a website on AWS Server at that time Scheduler is not running.

In AWS Server Instance, Using Task Scheduler pass the url of the page but some time this will not work.

Is there any another way to run scheduler everyday?

Comment: ASP.NET/IIS is not scheduled tasks. AWS provides you typical options, such as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Comment: @LexLi
I want to invoke a web url.It will support that

Comment: Technology does not always support what you want.